# Apache Storm scale/rebalance without downtime

Tags: apache-storm

I'm currently analysing Apache Storm if it is usable as Stream Processing Framework for me. It looks really nice, but what worries me, is the scaling.
As far as I understood it, scaling is done by rebalancing.

e.g. If I wan't to add a new server to the cluster, I have to increase the `workers`. But when I do so with

```
storm rebalance storm_example -n 4
```

all the `bolts` and `spouts` stop working while it is rebalancing. But what I want is more like:

*Add the Server, add a new worker on it, and when new Data arrive, also consider this new one to work off the data*

Do I just don't get the idea of Storm or is that not possible with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar requirement and as per my research it is not possible. In my case we ended up creating a new storm cluster without disturbing the existing one. We were (are) trying to assign servers/workers based on the load to storm to avoid AWS cost. 

It would be interesting to know if we can do so.